# Disable menu close/hide after click on menu item

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs5

I am using ExtJs 5.1
Need to be able not to close the menu after there is a click on menu item.
My menu is defined inside of a buton like this:

```
Ext.define('ContextualButton', {
extend: 'Ext.button.Button',
alias: 'widget.contextual_help',
menuAlign: 'tr-br',
articleLimit: 5,

listeners: {
    click: function(menu) {
        menu.show();
    }
},

menu: {
    id: 'contextual-menu-list',
    cls: 'contextual-submenu',
    width: 400,
    height: 600,
    shadowOffset: 15,
    scrollable: null,
    margin: '30 0 0 0',

    listeners: {
        click: function(menu, item, e) {
            menu.ownerCmp.onArticleClick(menu, item, e);
        }
    },
```

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Can you provide a [Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#home) example?  This code is incomplete and doesn't really show what you're trying to accomplish... you want the menu to close after you click a menu item?  That usually happens automatically anyway...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a [hideOnClick](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.0-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.menu.Item-cfg-hideOnClick) property on [Ext.menu.Item](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.0-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.menu.Item) that can be set to *false* (default is *true*).

```
/**
 * @cfg {Boolean} hideOnClick
 * Whether to not to hide the owning menu when this item is clicked.
 */
hideOnClick: true
```

here is simple [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/10au) with [hideOnClick](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.0-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.menu.Item-cfg-hideOnClick) property implemented.